# Do I need an airport transit visa for Amsterdam

Tags: visas, transit-visas, filipino-citizens, ams

I am a Philippines passport holder working in Kazakhstan. From Kazakhstan I would like to fly to USA but I will have a 2 hour and 30 minute layover in Amsterdam AMS Airport.

Do I need an airport transit visa?

Answer (score 0):

Only nationals of the following countries need transit visas in Schengen countries like the Netherlands:

- Afghanistan
- Bangladesh
- Congo (Democratic Republic)
- Eritrea
- Ethiopia
- Ghana
- Iran
- Iraq
- Nigeria
- Pakistan
- Somalia
- Sri Lanka

The Philippines, as you see, is not on the list.

Comment: [I don't think your list is correct](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/e-library/documents/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/docs/annex_7b_atv-national_lists.en.pdf) (the list also differs between member states – notably citizens of the Philippine would need an airport transit visa for French airports).